# Android: creating transition/animation with countdown timer

Tags: android, timer

I'm trying to make a timer and an associated animation with it. Starting from the basics, I have created a countdown timer and a white line below it:

[image]

Now, I want the white divider view to become red in color - pixel by pixel (left to right) as the remaining time keeps getting short. 
For example, if half of the time has passed, I want the divider to be turned half-red from coordinates 0 to dividerLength/2.

Here is the divider xml code:

```
        <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timer"/>
```

Here's my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView mTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
    final View divider = (View)findViewById(R.id.divider);
    final int x = 2;     //x will be supplied in minutes.


    new CountDownTimer(x*1000*60, 1000) {

        int secsPassed = 0;
        int minsPassed = 0;
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            secsPassed++;
            minsPassed = (secsPassed-1)/60;


            int minsRemaining = x - minsPassed-1;
            int secondsRemaining = 60-secsPassed%60;
            String secs, mins;
            //Here I'll write logic for proper formatting of mins and secs
            mTextField.setText(mins + ":" + secs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

How can I make the line color change pixel by pixel with time?

Comment: see `android.widget.ProgressBar`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using ProgressBar now and that's working perfectly.